# Is the 0-1 Knapsack that each item has the same weight NP-complete?

Tags: algorithm, np-complete, np

The 0-1 Knapsack problem is known as NP-complete. But if the weight for each item are the same, the problem is still NP-complete?

Comment: Imagine a stash box in Diablo (or your favorite similar analogy) where you can stash loot. If *all items take one "cell"* (or "have a weight of 1"), how can it be arranged so that only the "best stuff" (e.g. most expensive stuff) is kept? How do you know what things *not* to stash? The 2d stash box can be simplified to a 1d belt due to *lack of weight/size*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because you always just take whatever items are the most valuable.

Comment: How do you prove that this is optimal?