# Is the variation of Knapsack NP-Complete?

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, np

In the knapsack problem, the only constraint is that the total size of picked items is no larger than the total size of the package. We know the Knapsack problem is NP-Complete.

However, if we have another constraint of choosing fixed number of items, is this problem still NP-Complete? The formal description of the problem is shown as follows,

Maximize  $\sum_{j=1}^n p_j x_j$

s.t.      $\sum_{j=1}^n w_j x_j < W$

```
      $\sum_{j=1}^n x_j = N$

      $x_j = \{0,1\}$
```

This is a formulated problem in my research and I am not sure whether it is NP-Complete or not. Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: If you are having trouble with basic complexity issues (and [some](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249448/is-the-0-1-knapsack-that-each-item-has-the-same-weight-np-complete) of your questions suggest you do) even though you are doing actual research, I would suggest to read up on the matter; this question is something that a basic working knowledge should have cleared up. Also, I think one of your variables is off; you probably meant to say w_j in the first two sums?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will read more on the complexity concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve the constrained problem by iterating over all combinations of size `N` from your set of `n` objects. The number of combinations is no more than `n^N`:

```
C = n! / (N! (n-N)!)
 <= n! / (n-N)!                // since N! >= 1
  = n * (n-1) * ... * (n-N+1)  // N terms
 <= n * n * ... * n            // N terms
  = n^N
```

Since `N` is fixed, the overall complexity is therefore polynomial.

Comment: Or, more expressly, if he can use a maximum of k elements from an n element set, he has [sum of j = 1 to k]:(n choose j) possibilities, which is in O(n^(2^k)), which is polynomial in n for every fixed k. For choosing exactly k elements, we end up with checking O(n choose k) = O(n^k) subsets.